# Does anybody know of a tutorial for a gallery which works on mobile/touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, gallery

I'm looking to use a javascript gallery to display images on mobile devices such as the iPhone.

I really like the look of the jqtouch gallery which is a jquery extension but can't find a tutorial on how to set it up anywhere.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a documented image gallery with jquery.

http://neteye.github.com/touch-gallery.html

Also you can use sencha touch, carousel will work fine for you. here is kitchen sink demo that you can see on your iphone.(it is not so much easy to learn at first, but sencha is my best mobile javascript framework. It will worth to learn it)

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

And you can also look for a jquery extension too that mocks this carousel, code is so short that you can easily understand.

http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/12/jquery-mobile-carousel-sencha-style.html